# Apache Web Server port 433 and Tomcat port 8080, redirect not working

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat9

My Apache webserver runs on port 433 with https protocol. I wish to run Tomcat on port 8080 because there is no need for additional encryption, Tomcat is on the same machine, so I don't need port 8433. But when I forward traffic from 433 to 8080 via `iptables` but I got an error: This site can’t provide a secure connection

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

What configurations do I need in tomcat server.xml and apache.conf to make this work?

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- I've tried this before when I thought I need an SSL for Tomcat. I think it's irrelevant now -->
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin root@localhost
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
     DirectoryIndex index.html
     ServerName mydomain.zone
     ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/mydomain.zone.error_log"
     CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/mydomain.zone.access_log" common
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.zone
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf
```

EDIT:
I have tried, as suggested, with `ProxyPass "/" "http://mydomain.zone:8080/"` and `ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://mydomain.zone:8080/"`. Still the same issue.

I wondered if there was any `iptables` rule that I implemented before, but it doesn't seem so. These are current active iptables rules:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_direct
-N FWDI_trusted
-N FWDI_trusted_allow
-N FWDI_trusted_deny
-N FWDI_trusted_log
-N FWDO_trusted
-N FWDO_trusted_allow
-N FWDO_trusted_deny
-N FWDO_trusted_log
-N INPUT_ZONES
-N INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N INPUT_direct
-N IN_trusted
-N IN_trusted_allow
-N IN_trusted_deny
-N IN_trusted_log
-N OUTPUT_direct
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i eth0 -g FWDI_trusted
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_trusted
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o eth0 -g FWDO_trusted
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_trusted
-A FWDI_trusted -j FWDI_trusted_log
-A FWDI_trusted -j FWDI_trusted_deny
-A FWDI_trusted -j FWDI_trusted_allow
-A FWDI_trusted -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_trusted -j FWDO_trusted_log
-A FWDO_trusted -j FWDO_trusted_deny
-A FWDO_trusted -j FWDO_trusted_allow
-A FWDO_trusted -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_ZONES -i eth0 -g IN_trusted
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_trusted
-A IN_trusted -j IN_trusted_log
-A IN_trusted -j IN_trusted_deny
-A IN_trusted -j IN_trusted_allow
-A IN_trusted -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proxy pass instead of using iptables for port forwarding

Comment: I have deleted my iptables rule and I've inserted:
`ProxyPass / http://www.mydomain.zone:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mydomain.zone:8080`
Now I have error:  Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later. (Tomcat is running I checked and Apache is restarted).
Can you give me a more detailed answer?

Comment: ProxyPass "/"  "http://www.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://www.example.com/"

Answer (score 0):

ProxyPass "/"  "http://www.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://www.example.com/"

modify your proxypass as mentioned above

Comment: I wrote this in conf/httpd.conf. It's not working. Maybe I should write it in conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf or in conf.d/ssl.conf?

Comment: **ProxyPass "/" "https://www.example.com/" ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://www.example.com/"** use this since it is a secure connection port you are trying to access . Ie use https insted of http

Comment: I got working solved in ubuntu, but in Centos Stream 9 i feel very lost